# How to persist and authenticate users from an MVC application to a Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

So we are currently looking to build out a site that utilizes a Web API for all of our authentication and communication with the database. What we are unsure of at the moment is how to persist users in our MVC application by authenticating through the Web API.

Where does this happen on the MVC side of things and how should we be authenticating with the Web API?

EDIT: Another thing I am wondering is if we can make a call to the API to get an Identity user after they are authenticated and instantiate the identity user on the MVC side of things and just store them in a session variable to persist on our application. Would this be doable and any idea what it would look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC utilizes the session for authentication. A cookie is sent to the user, and the web browser sends that cookie back with each request to enable to the server to restore the session and recognize the user as authenticated.

Web Api is REST-based and *stateless*. There's no concept of a session, cookies, etc. Each Web Api request must be authenticated in the request, usually by passing an `Authorization` header with a bearer token or similar.

If the MVC application utilizes the Web Api to authenticate, then the Web Api should return an authentication token to the MVC application. The MVC application then, should "log in" the user by setting that normal authentication cookie and save the token so that it can authenticate future Web Api requests with that. In other words, the MVC application still handles authorization as it normally does. The only difference is that the response of the Web Api determines whether or not it considers the username/password combo to be correct, rather than a database query made directly.

Comment: I would add that all requests made to the WebAPI backend should also be authenticated (the token should be passed in the Authorization header and checked).  it's not enough to handle authentication/authorization on the MVC side of things as anyone trying to maliciously break your system will be attacking your WepAPI directly, they won't be using your MVC client to do so.

Comment: In my answer I said: "save the token so that it can authenticate future Web Api requests with that". But, just in case that wasn't explicit enough, yes.